# What's causing my Class linkage error when deploying to the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, ios-simulator, firemonkey

I'm trying to run a very simple (Hello World-ish) Fire Monkey app to an iOS Simulator (Mac Mini) from Delphi-XE7 (Windows 7).

When I do this I get a "Class linkage error", and a Trouble shooting window that contains the same text as this [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/RunIOSSimulatorFailedHelpPage).

Working through this:

- I've verified that my connection profile is set up

  - And that it's able to talk to the Platform Assistant server (/w a Passwordl.
  - I've verified this by turning it off and using the Test Connection button to see that it fails when it is off and works when it is on.
- I've added the SDK Manager for iOS Simulator (iPhoneSimulator 8.3)
- I've added the SDK Manager for iOS Device (iPhoneOS 8.3)
- I've get Xcode (6.3) started on the MAC.
- I've got iOS Simulator already started

What have I missed?

I'll note that I don't see Phone Simulators for iOS 7.1, 8.1, or 8.2 even though they are installed for Xcode when I add the SDK Managers - I'm wondering if that is at all related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue with deploying iOS 8 code from Delphi XE7. Actually, it seems to be more to do with the version of Xcode (as of 2015-04-22 the latest version is 6.3).

The latest version of XCode that works with Delphi XE7 is 5.1.1. Downgrading from Xcode 6.3 to Xcode 5.1.1 has solved my issues. Delphi had other cryptic issues with Xcode 6.0.1 and above.

I'll note that the latest version of iOS that Xcode 5.1.1 capable deploying is 7.1, which is also the oldest version (as of 2015-04-22) that the AppStore will support. However, the App store will not support any new application in 7.1.  So your path is to move to XE8 and I presume they've fixed the problems talking to XCode 6.x there.